Order of the transpose in squaring matrix expression
I'm going through some econometrics, and I was just curious as to how to determine the order of the transpose for squaring a matrix expression.
For example, when solving for OLS, we have $\hat\beta = \underset{b}{\arg\min} \; \mathbb{E}[(y - \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{\beta})^2]$, and we have the transpose first, I.e. $(y - \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{\beta})^2 = (y - \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{\beta})^T(y - \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{\beta}) \rightarrow y^2 - 2\beta\mathbf{x}y + \beta^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\beta$.
But later on, with the variance of $\hat\beta$, we have:
$Var(\hat\beta|\mathbf{X}) = \mathbb{E}[(\hat\beta - \mathbb{E}[\hat\beta|\mathbf{X}])^2|\mathbf{X}] = \mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{e}\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}|\mathbf{X}]$ (With $\hat\beta - \mathbb{E}[\hat\beta|\mathbf{X}] = (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{e}$).
Why do we use $((\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{e})((\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{e})^T$ in this case rather than the transpose first?
I know that having the transpose first would leave us a scalar, whereas this gives us a matrix, but it's an unsatisfying explanation. It seems arbitrary to select an order that gives us a dimension that we're looking for rather than a 'correct' procedure to how to order this. Am I missing a fundamental property of matrices here?

If these details are confusing, it would probably be best to do away with the notation of squaring a matrix/vector altogether, and to be fully precise by using only transposition and matrix multiplication. You'd need a different definition of the least squares objective and the variance of a vector for this.

I'd like to just use matrix multiplication, but I'm trying to understand these definitions in the textbooks and materials that my professors give me, and this is how they define least squares etc. Is there a justification/reason for why this difference exists?

There's nothing "arbitrary" about performing the operations correctly!  In the end, this is purely a matter of following the rules of matrix multiplication along with the convention (in your case) that vectors are column vectors.  Dimensionality considerations are (extremely) useful heuristics for writing things down correctly.

How am I sure which one is 'correct' though? Both are valid operations, but one gives a matrix and the other a scalar. If I'm in an unfamiliar context, how do I decide which way to multiply?
